# Power Automate - Set Column value to equal value of another Column in same list

Tags: column, calculated-column-formula, power-automate, json, column-formatting

I have a modern list with about 5,000 entries.  My client has added two columns since creating all this data, and I need to set one column to equal the value of the other (doing this manually will take too long).  I need the values from the "Location" Column (calculated), to populate the "Title Link" column (Hyperlink/Picture).

[image]

So the "Title Link" column should equal the "Location" column.  I'm not sure if JSON or Power Automate would be the better option.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the calculation/formula for calculated column? You cannot save/set value using JSON formatting (It will only show in list view). You can run Power automate flow & update the SP list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you could try:

First, change (or delete and recreate) your Title Link column to be a calculated column, where the formula would be =Location

Otherwise, you could create a Flow in Power Automate. Choose to trigger it manually, add a "get items" action to pull all the items in your list, then an "update items" action to write the dynamic content from Location into the Title Link field. In this case, you wouldn't want Title Link to be a calculated field.

The first solution will help if you add any more rows with Location Data to your list: they will automatically display in your Title Link field. You won't be able to add any links to your Title Link field directly, though.

The second solution would allow you to add subsequent info directly to your Title Link field, but would need to be run again manually (or set up with an automatic trigger) if you have any more list items added with data in the Location field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  So I went with the Power Automate option.  I created a new single-line text column ("Test Column") and set the flow to update that column based on the Location column.  The Location column (calculated) creates a hyperlink out of the text.  However, my flow is copying the URL, rather than the Hyperlink itself.  Should I have created the new column to also be a Calculated field?

Comment: I don't think you should use a calculated field, or the Flow will be duplicating what the calculated field is already trying to do, and if I recall correctly you can't instruct your flow to update a calculated field with the Update Items action. I don't have experience with the issue of getting field content to display as a hyperlink instead of text, but a quick search on that may turn up an answer. You may need to use a column type of hyperlink, rather than single line of text.